# Unable to get Topic Exchange to Work in RabbitMQ AMQP 1.0

Tags: c#, amqp, amqpnetlite

I am finding it very difficult to work with RabbitMQ and AMQP 1.0, particularly as it pertains to topic exchanges using AMQPNetLite.  I am unable to send a message using a topic exchange to a specific queue.  I'm not even using wildcards.

My situation is super simple too.  I have one topic exchange.  I have one queue that the topic exchange sends to.  When I send to the topic exchange, the queue never receives the message.

```
test.exchange:
  bind: testqueue - routing key: test

testqueue:
  bound to exchange with routing key: test
```

The AMQP 1.0 documentation says that the "Subject" is the routing key right?  Well when I use AMQPNetLite to send to RabbitMQ, it appears to connect, and the topic appears to have received the message, but it is never routed to the queue.

Here's the entire code:

```cs
            var rabbitMqAddress = $"amqp://127.0.0.1:5672";
            var address = new Address(rabbitMqAddress);
            var producerName = $"Producer-test.topic-{Time.GetTimeStamp()}";

            var connection = new Connection(address, null, new Open
            {
                ContainerId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ChannelMax = 64,
            }, null);

            var session = new Session(connection);
            var senderLink = new SenderLink(session, producerName, "/topic/test.exchange");

            senderLink.Send(new Message
            {
                BodySection = new AmqpValue { Value = "test 123" },
                Properties = new Properties
                {
                    Subject = "test",
                }
            });
```

[image]

The image proves the binding.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you mix two ways of doing it.
Either you publish to address "/topic/test" -where test is your routingkey
OR
you publish to "/exchange/test.exchange" and set the Subject-property to "test".

Both works. if you use the "/topic/"-prefix in your address you are going through the default "amq.topic"-exchange and not your own "test-exchange".

made sense?
more information in the "Routing and Addressing"-secion here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0

Comment: Thank you.  I had to step away from this and take a breather.  I added this to the test suite, and boom it worked.  Sometimes I have to step back and let it sit.  Configuration details is not on my plate in this context, programmatic implementation is though.  We have a base library 1.0 capable because of the tech stack, however we want to use the same library (so we don't duplicate code) for RabbitMQ.  As a fail safe, RabbitMQ client is in and configurable at the lower level, allowing us to switch to either.  Thanks again!