# How to exchange AMQP 1.0 messages using fe2o3-amqp and RabbitMQ with Topic Exchange

Tags: rust, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to use the fe2o3-amqp crate (Rust) for receiving and sending messages through a RabbitMQ broker configured with the AMQP 1.0 protocol.

How do I configure the `Connection`, `Session` and `Sender`/`Receiver` for publishing/subscribing to a topic exchange?

This is what I've done so far. For topic exchange in RabbitMQ, I've configured an Exchange (named `MyExchange`, Durable, Type: Topic), a Queue (named `MyQueue`, type: Classic, Durable), and a Binding from `MyExchange` to `MyQueue` with routing key `my.topic`.

Using a Python script with pika, on Python 3.9.2, I can send messages to `my.topic` that can be viewed enqueued in `MyQueue`. I'm not sure here pika is using AMQP version 1.0, but at least it confirms the exchange-routing-queue is working. The relevant part in python is as simple as follows, the rest is just glue (simply creating channel and connection):

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='MyExchange', routing_key='my.topic', body='Hello topic!')
```

This is what most examples in documentation do, except examples don't use the `Sender::builder()`:

```
    let mut connection = create_connection(
        "a-sender",
        "blah-blah",
    ).await?;

    let session = Session::begin(&mut connection).await?;

    let sender = Sender::builder()
        .name("rust-sender-link-1")
        .target("some-queue-name")
        .attach(&mut session)
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

If I use `MyQueue` as `"my.topic"` it fails with error code `SenderAttachError`. Any other queue name just creates a new queue.

So, how do I specify the exchange and route?

BR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @minghua-wu, the author of [fe2o3-amqp crate](https://crates.io/crates/fe2o3-amqp), for providing useful [comments](https://github.com/minghuaw/fe2o3-amqp/issues/195#issuecomment-1430247536) very promptly in the [project's page](https://github.com/minghuaw/fe2o3-amqp) on github.

There is a helpful question that was posted here a while ago, [Unable to get Topic Exchange to Work in RabbitMQ AMQP 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800475/unable-to-get-topic-exchange-to-work-in-rabbitmq-amqp-1-0).

The target's name for attaching the sender/receiver to a session must include the route root `/exchange/my.topic` for indicating explicitly that the topic will be related to a specific exchange-topic. Otherwise attachment will fail, or will occur to the broker's default topic exchange and messages will be sent to another queue.

Prior to this, in RabbitMQ broker, the exchange's filter must be configured for routing messages to the appropriated queue. Last but not least, also the user permissions must be configured so access to this topic is granted.

```rust
// "test.topic"
let sender = Sender::attach(&mut session, "amq_topic_sender", "/exchange/my_exchange/my.topic").await.unwrap();
let receiver = Receiver::attach(&mut session, "amq_topic_receiver", "/exchange/my_exchange/my.topic").await.unwrap();
```